# How to load child page before loading parent page?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, tabs

I have a parent page and some tabs in that page...Each tab will display a page,that is, I have some 6 pages in one jsp page....My problem is when I am loading the main page,part of the main page is first loaded and it is taking some time to load the pages in the tabs....So it looks weird...How can I avoid this....Is there any way to load the child pages first internally and then displaying parent page? Or is there any other way to solve this ?....
I have included the pages like below....
The below code is to create the tabs.....

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li id="planDetails-tab"><a id="hrefPlanDetailsid" accesskey="p" href="#divPlanDetailsTab" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;Plan Details</a></li>
        <li id="testPlan-tab"><a id="hrefTestPlanid" accesskey="t" href="#divTestPlanTab" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Test Plan&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>                        
        <li id="serviceArea-tab"><a href="#divServiceAreaTab" accesskey="s" class="planTabHeader">Service Area</a></li>
        <li id="rates-tab"><a href="#divRatesTab" accesskey="r" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Rates&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li id="benefits-tab"><a href="#divBenefitsTab" accesskey="b" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Benefits&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li id="network-tab"><a href="#divNetworkEcpTab" accesskey="n" class="planTabHeader">Network ECP</a></li>
        <li id="historical-tab"><a href="#divHistoricalTab" accesskey="h" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;Historical&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li id="directory-tab"><a href="#divDirectoryTab" accesskey="d" class="planTabHeader">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Directory&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The below code is about how I include pages...(I have mentioned only one page for reference)

```
<s:include value="PlanDetail.jsp" />
```

Comment: why don't load your contents only when you click on the child tab?.

Comment: but how to do that....And when the main page is loaded for the first time,first tab should also be loaded...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSP single page, what you can do is minimal. Because once the server render the whole JSP it sends content to the browser and browser will present it. So I suggest you use AJAX to get your content and dynamically put them in tabs as you get into them.

Or you can make your child page to have a part where it loads the parent page (or page navigator). In this way delay will be shorter since its also get compiled in the server side.

Comment: I solved the problem....Now I have another issue...In firefox,when the main page is loaded,it is getting refreshed as many times as the number of tabs in that page...How can I avoid this?